# What's the difference between path.reset() and create new one?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-developer-api, android-graphics

In Android  android.graphics.Path is it better to use the same path instance and do path.reset() or just create a new one(new Path()) whenever drawing new thing?

```
Path path = new Path();
path.lineTo(...); // some drawing
path.reset()
path.lineTo(...); // more drawing


Path path = new Path();
path.lineTo(...); // some drawing
path = new Path();
path.lineTo(...); // more drawing
```

Are there any differences ?

Answer (score 2):

Allocations are expensive.  In onDraw code, a reset is preferred as its cheaper (in general you should minimize calls to new in onDraw and anything called from there).  If the path is being created outside of onDraw or other performance critical areas then it matters less and new probably feels more readable/maintainable.